# Not able to upload image to the server using web service in windows phone 8 app

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, json.net

I a new to windows development. I tried a lot to upload an image to the server, but I am unable to do so.

If anyone can help me out, please see my code below

```
void uploadphoto()
{
    WebClient webClient1 = new WebClient();
        webClient1.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient1_DownloadStringCompleted);
    webClient1.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("Web Service"));
}

void webClient1_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
        var rootobject1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject1>(e.Result);
    int error = rootobject1.response.errorFlag;
        string message = rootobject1.response.msg;
    if (error == 0)
            {
                    MessageBox.Show(message);
            }
        else
            {
                    MessageBox.Show(message);
            }
}

public class Response1
{
        public int errorFlag { get; set; }
        public string msg { get; set; }
        public List<string> uploadedImageNames { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject1
{
        public Response1 response { get; set; }
}
```

And I am using the code below for selecting the image:

```
private void ImageUpload(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBoxResult mb = MessageBox.Show("Select the mode of uploading the picture", "", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
        Popup popup = new Popup();
        photoSelection photo = new photoSelection();
        popup.Child = photo;
        popup.IsOpen = true;
        photo.camera.Click += (s, args) =>
            {
                photoCameraCapture.Show();
                popup.IsOpen = false;
            };
        photo.library.Click += (s, args) =>
            {
                photoChooserTask.Show();
                popup.IsOpen = false;
            };
}
```

I am using those code for developing app for Windows Phone 8. I am using Json.Net.Please help me out. Thanx in advance.

**EDIT**

```
private void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        this.imageTribute.Source = image;
        byte[] bytearray = null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {

            if (imageTribute.Source == null)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                WriteableBitmap wbitmp = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)imageTribute.Source);

                wbitmp.SaveJpeg(ms, 40, 40, 0, 82);
                bytearray = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
        strimage = Convert.ToBase64String(bytearray);
    }
```

I am using this code for choosing and converting to base64 and then I passed it to web service.

Comment: this is very difficult to follow, you're ImageUpload doesn't seem to interact at all with any web service and the only code that does interact with a service does a download of a string.  I would consult some of the samples at http://dev.windowsphone.com, perhaps the [Auto-upload sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Auto-upload-Sample-0afb5b95) will have the service code you're looking for (and a lot more that you don't need in this context)

Comment: Actually I am converting image to base64 string after choosing it. And that string I am passing to the webservice.

Comment: And if possible, you can edit my code and tell me how to do it. By the way I will refer whatever links you gave and return to you. Thanx alot.